# Android Studio GUI is broken / glitchy

Tags: windows, user-interface, android-studio

Having some serious issues getting Android Studio to work correctly. This is quite the annoyance as I don't really know how the phrase this into something simple but here goes:

When I first launch Android Studio all works great, but after a while the actual GUI of the program becomes buggy and starts to overlap each other based on where I point my mouse. I'm talking about the GUI of the IDE itself and not what it simulates as the application view.

[image: a]

This is making the application unusable and I have no idea how to fix it. Any ideas?

Comment: This is most likely caused by your installed JVM, try either update your JVM or modify graphics related flags listed here: http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/configuration

Answer (score 0):

Close Android Studio.
Create a file idea.properties in Android Studio configuration folder located in C:/Users/"Username"/.AndroidStudio[versionNumber]
Add this line: sun.java2d.d3d=false
Restart Android Studio